# Dynamic Url on Axios Get Express

Tags: node.js, express, axios, request

I tried to hit third party API with Axios express js
here's my code

**controller.js**

```
let randNumb = '129383'
let response = await api.get(randNumb) 
console.log(response)
```

**api.js**

```
const axios = require('axios').default;
let API = {}
api.get = (randNumb) =>{
const url= process.env.Host+randNumb+'/result'
 var config = {
      method: 'get',
      url: url,
      headers: { 
        'Accept': '*/*'
      }
    };
    await axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
      return JSON.stringify(response.data)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

But I keep getting status 412 For hit that API but when I hardcoded that URL like :

`let url= https://thridParty.com/129383/result` on api.js it getting worked.
I need to custom or dynamic this URL
could you guys help me?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation of that third party API ?

Comment: Please run a `console.log(url)` right after setting the variable.

Comment: @Seblor I 've done check the documentation and i can run it in postman

Comment: @JonathanNielsen i've done console.log and the return of the console it same like that I harcoded. i really confused

Answer (score 0):

```
// Does not work
const url = process.env.Host + randNumb + '/result'

// Does work
const url = 'https://thridParty.com/129383/result'
```

If this is like you said, then maybe the concatenated string does not result in a valid url.
Please check the value of the `url` variable, it will probably not look like the hard coded url, might miss a slash or something else.

Comment: I already console.log and makesure that the thirdparty API is valid